# How can JavaScript get a file size in Internet Explorer 8 and Internet Explorer 9 (browser side)?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, file-upload, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I was unable to find any solution for Internet Explorer 8 and Internet Explorer 9 that allows me to know the file size via [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), so I can have a client-side validation (along with the one in the backend) and show an error message if the file the user is trying to upload is bigger than a certain size.

Solutions I have found so far involve [ActiveX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) and [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash), but I would like to avoid that.

Can this be done in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no JavaScript-only polyfill/shim/etc. for this feature on browsers like IE8 and IE9 that don't support the [File API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi). Nor can there be. That's *why* we have the File API in modern browsers.

If you feel strongly about offering client-side validation to supplement your server-side validation, you'll have to go with ActiveX, Flash, or [Java applet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) solutions.